# How to generate correctly svg images

Tags: svg, photoshop, sketch-3, zeplin

I am trying to generate an SVG format file for a logo but I don't know how to proceed.

Usually when I need an svg format, I upload the image to Zeplin and it is auto generated. I tried to do the same thing this time but it tells me `This layer contains bitmap images, so no vector assets were generated.` What are bitmap images? How do I remove them or transform into something else? Thanks!

(I'm not a designer)

Comment: 1.) If I understand correctly you're you wanting to convert the svg file to png? or vice versa?
2.) What os are you on?

Comment: I have a `.png` and I want to convert it to `.svg`. I'm using mac.

Comment: "Bitmap image"  is just a general term for images that are based on pixels. Examples are PNG, GIF, JPEG, BMP, or Photoshop files.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `.png` file to a `.svg` file by using the `convert` command.

`convert` comes with the ImageMagick program.

1.) ImageMagick is not installed by default so if you don't already have it, get [macport](https://www.macports.org/install.php) and install it.

**NOTE: If you don't want to install macport, you can just download and install ImageMagick directly from [HERE](http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/) and skip to step 3**

2.) Open a terminal and enter:
`sudo port install ImageMagick`

3.) Open a terminal in the directory of the image and enter:
`convert filename.png filename.svg`

You will now have the converted image in svg format.

Comment: Imagemagick is a raster image processor. It does not create vector files. If you input a vector file such as SVG it will produce a raster output. You cannot use it to convert a raster PNG into a vector SVG. What you will get is the raster image imbedded as pixels or points in an SVG vector shell. You need a proper raster to vector tool, such as autotrace or protrace.